# vgaswitcheroo status change

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel, opensuse

I use opensuse and ubuntu linux.

In order to see my current video cart, I do something like this:

`cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switc`h

and the result is this:

```
    0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
    1:DIS: :Pwr:0000:01:00.0
```

That does IGD aand DIS means?

when I try to disable my Video card like this:

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

after that command, I have that result:

```
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0
```

As I understand "DIS" is disabled. now my video card is disabled, is not it (is it enough)? and what does Pwr means here? and what is that "0000:00:02.0" numbers?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a list of the graphics cards you have in your machine.

0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0 <- This is your integrated card.  (Something like an Intel 3000 HD)
1:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0 <- This is your discrete card. (Something like ATI Radeon 6700M)

The '+' will indicate the card that is currently driving the display of your computer.  And the 'Pwr'/Off will be the card status.

So currently your discrete card is off. Your integrated card is on and driving the display.